# AWS ALB Ingress with backend service of type Nodeport is sending host as ip address instead of actual host

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have few services running in the backend which i am planning to expose using alb-ingress. The service is set of type Nodeport. We have some domain name checks in the code and i am getting the node ip address instead of the host name there.

I couldn't find any documentation on setting the host header for ALB ingress. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/

Comment: @harshmanvar thanks for the link. I have followed the same to do the setup. However instead of getting subdomain.domain.com for host i am getting the node ip in the application